# Intercept loading of a certain page

Tags: hooks, template-redirect

Depending on whether user registration is enabled on my site or not, I want to prevent loading of my custom login form and display a popup instead telling the user that registration is disabled.

I have tried to find my way through the Wordpress Codex, but it is rather huge, so I didn't find what I was looking for.

How would the code look like that would do what I want, or what would be the proper Wordpress hook and the proper way to make Wordpress load my popup instead of the login page?

Comment: How is your custom login form called and used?  Is it in a page template or are you calling `wp_login_form()`?

Comment: It is a regular wordpress page and is invoked via a login icon in the site's header.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to intercept the page load with the `template_redirect` action and test user status before rending the login page.  Based on user status you could redirect to another page instead of loading the original page content.

```
function wpse_is_user_good_enough() {
    if ( ! is_page( 'your-login-page-slug-here' ) ) {
        return;  // Not the login page so return early
    }

    // The login page is loading. Ck user status here and bounce them or send them along
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_is_user_good_enough' );
```

The above example will hook the wpse_is_user_good_enough function to the template_redirect action.  Test right away if this is the page you wish to intercept; return if not.

If you have a PHP template dedicated to the login page, you can embed your user status test on the page template and skip the rest.  Using a page template would allow you to display alternate content instead of redirecting an unauthorized user.